# Angular 4 "export 'AnimationEvent' was not found in '@angular/animations'

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

Angular version 4.3.2

@angular/cli version 1.2.6

I'm using TypeScript (v2.4.2) for a component that imports

```
import {animate, AnimationEvent, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
```

I'm getting warnings that say

> "export 'AnimationEvent' was not found in '@angular/animations'

The other functions (animate, state, style, etc.) trigger no warnings.  I discovered that the @angular code in node_modules/@angular/animations.d.ts includes

```
export * from './public_api';
```

and ./public_api.d.ts has

```
export * from './src/animations';
```

and ./src/animations.d.ts has

```
export { AnimationBuilder, AnimationFactory } from './animation_builder';
export { AnimationEvent } from './animation_event';
export { AUTO_STYLE, AnimateChildOptions, AnimateTimings, AnimationAnimateChildMetadata, AnimationAnimateMetadata, AnimationAnimateRefMetadata, AnimationGroupMetadata, AnimationKeyframesSequenceMetadata, AnimationMetadata, AnimationMetadataType, AnimationOptions, AnimationQueryMetadata, AnimationQueryOptions, AnimationReferenceMetadata, AnimationSequenceMetadata, AnimationStaggerMetadata, AnimationStateMetadata, AnimationStyleMetadata, AnimationTransitionMetadata, AnimationTriggerMetadata, animate, animateChild, animation, group, keyframes, query, sequence, stagger, state, style, transition, trigger, useAnimation, ɵStyleData } from './animation_metadata';
export { AnimationPlayer, NoopAnimationPlayer } from './players/animation_player';
export * from './private_export';
```

and ./animation_event.d.ts has the interface definition

```
export interface AnimationEvent {
    fromState: string;
    toState: string;
    totalTime: number;
    phaseName: string;
    element: any;
    triggerName: string;
}
```

If I copy the interface definition into my code everything works fine.

All of this is quite similar to many other imports I've used but this is the only one that generates warnings.

How can I prevent these warnings without copying the interface definition into my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**app-module.ts**: Did you import BrowserAnimationsModule?

See [here](https://angular.io/guide/animations) in docs.

Along with a plunker [example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/animations/eplnkr.html).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ],
})
```

If that doesn't solve it:

- Make a note of what **system.config.js** is doing in the Plunker.
- Another related resource is a [github issues thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14728).

Be sure to comment which steps if any fixed it. ;-)

Comment: I did import BrowserAnimationsModule and all my animations are working as expected.  In fact, except for the compiler warnings, everything is running and working as expected.

Comment: TL;DR Fixed by changing tsconfig.js compilerOptions.module from 'es2015' to 'CommonJS'.  Assuming this must be a compiler configuration, I analyzed the systemjs.config.js in the Plunker to compare with my (Angular CLI generated) tsconfig.app.json file.  There were only two differences, 1) noImplicitAny: true, and 2) module: 'commonjs'.  I changed both, one at a time.  The TypeScript doc states that the module type is CommonJS so I used that.  I hope this change won't cause other problems down the road...

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html --noImplicitAny Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. So that might not have been necessary. But glad you resolved it.

Comment: I should have said that I changed the noImplicitAny back to its default value because I had *lots* of implicit 'any' declarations :)