# when typing ng serve im getting this error

Tags: javascript, angular

[cmd screenshot***strong text***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGMQx.png)

```
"export 'AnimationEngine' (imported as 'ɵngcc1') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/animations.js 231:73-95
"export 'AnimationEngine' (imported as 'ɵngcc1') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/animations.js 380:209-240
"export 'AnimationStyleNormalizer' (imported as 'ɵngcc1') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/animations.js 392:60-91
"export 'AnimationStyleNormalizer' (imported as 'ɵngcc1') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser'
```

Comment: please check if this question helps: [Angular 4 "export 'AnimationEvent' was not found in '@angular/animations'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470438/angular-4-export-animationevent-was-not-found-in-angular-animations)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's required here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may also help.  A [mcve] would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this first remove `node_modules` folder from your project & then again try to install npm using `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to run `npm i` first run this then run `ng serve`

if you have node_modules folder then first remove folder then run `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error after upgrading an Angular 2 app straight to Angular 10. After upgrading packages and adding packages to get everything working again, I got the same error after adding `BrowserAnimationsModule`. It was fixed by modifying `tsconfig.json` and settings `compilerOptions.module` to "esnext".

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "esnext", //<-- Set this to esnext. 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```